# Will re-installing MySQL remove or delete existing databases?

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, daemon

If I reinstall MySQL, without removing the actual MySQL installation, would it rewrite all files without deleting my databases?

My problem is my `mysqld` is broken, due to the fact that I accidentally copied a `.txt` file into it, ie:

```
#cp -f root.txt /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

It was a mistake, obviously the daemon wouldn't start anymore, by executing

```
service mysql start
```

How can I fix this? I guess I need to reinstall MySQL, but I wonder if I can just reinstall without affecting the databases in my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, no. When re-installing MySQL the existing databases are usually not removed. That's why you may see notes to drop the databases before you uninstall, if you go that way.

However, if you're still unsure, create a backup copy of the contents of the **data** folder, which will contain all your databases. You'll see a lot of [.frm files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html) inside.

Then after you re-install, and by some chance the data folder is empty, drop the contents back in.

Comment: If I delete the /usr/sbin/mysqld file, THEN reinstall mysql, then mysqld will be restored/rewrited?

Comment: You should just go for a clean un-install then re-install, because who knows what's really going on at this point. But backup your data folder just in case.